# Why don't we use const char* const for constant strings?

Tags: c++, string, constants

The standard way to store a constant string in C++ is to use `const char*`.
In the interest of precision and correctness, why don't we write `const char* const`?

Is this just because people are too lazy to write the extra `const`, or because it really does have some disadvantage?

**EDIT:** I guess I should have been more clear, I don't need an explanation for what `const` does in it's various positions, I know that much already. What I wanted to know is why the convention is to write `const char*` even for variables where you know you are never going to change the pointer. Is it just a matter of taste and style?

Comment: Same reasons you would/wouldn't put `const` on your other variables. There's nothing special about `const char*` variables when it comes to making a variable itself const.

Comment: To refer to a string literal using a pointer, the `const char*` part is required. The right side `const` it optional, and it's usually up to the developer to decide whether or not to use it. The principal of const correctness says that you should `const` anything that can be `const`, so someone who follows that principal would put both `const` if they can. Others might disagree, maybe they find it reduces readability or something. It's a matter of opinion.

Comment: So, for `const char* const text = "Foo";` - what would happen if you wanted `text` to later point to a different string literal (as would be possible without the second `const`). The extra `const` makes the variable a different beast.

Comment: I mean, the right const has nothing to do with the const ness of the string, it's of the pointer itself. I tend to find it's pretty rare people use it outside of the few occasions where a non-reassignable pointer, that also isn't a reference is actually useful.

Comment: _"The standard way to store a constant string ... use const char*"_  It's a common way, but it's certainly not standardized.  Please, feel free to use `const char* const`.

Comment: `const char*` does not **store** a constant string. It **points at** a constant string. The constant string is stored by its definition.

Comment: Second time today, someone closes a question, while I type my answer. Guess I won't bother any longer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A variable of type `int` can easily be modified by accident, by passing it to a function that takes `int&`. This is "invisible" at the call site, in the sense that calling a function that takes `int&` looks the same as calling a function that takes `int` or `const int&`. To guard against this, we make the variable `const` if possible.

With a variable of class type, not only do we have the above issue, but we also might modify it by accident by calling a non-`const` member function, which looks the same as a call to a `const` member function. So again, marking the variable `const` often helps catch bugs like this at compile time.

With `const char*` variables, it's rare that you'll accidentally modify them by passing them to functions taking `const char*&` (because such functions are rarely declared), and of course, pointers do not have member functions. Thus, protecting the pointed-to data with `const` is enough to prevent most unintended modifications. Of course, there could still have an assignment somewhere that changes the value of the pointer variable, but usually you can spot this during code review. If you want to write `const char* const` anyway, I see no reason not to, but some people will consider it as unnecessary clutter.

Comment: I think templates throw a small wrench in the whole thing of `const char*&` not being that common. Every (unconstrained) function template taking a `T&` contributes to this too.

Answer (score 2):

`const` applies to the thing on its left, unless there is nothing there, then it applies to the thing on its right instead.

In `const char *` (which can also be written as `char const *`), the `const` is on the `char`, not on the `*`.  So, this declares a *mutable* pointer to *immutable* `const char` data.  Data cannot be modified through the pointer, but the pointer itself can be freely changed to point at any `const char` memory, eg:

```cpp
const char *ptr = "string 1"; // OK
*ptr = 'S'; // illegal
ptr = "string 2"; // OK
```

In `const char * const` (which can also be written as `char const * const`), there is a `const` on the `char`, and there is a `const` on the `*`.  So, this declares an *immutable* `const` pointer to *immutable* `const char` data.  Data cannot be modified through the pointer, and the pointer itself cannot be changed once it has been initialized, eg:

```cpp
const char * const ptr = "string 1"; // OK
*ptr = 'S'; // illegal
ptr = "string 2"; // illegal
```

And just for completeness, let's also consider `char * const`. The `const` is on the `*`, not on the `char`.  So, this declares an *immutable* `const` pointer to *mutable* `char` data.  Data can freely be modified through the pointer, but the pointer itself cannot be changed once it has been initialized, eg:

```cpp
char buffer1[] = "string 1", buffer2[] = "string 2";
char * const ptr = buffer1; // OK
*ptr = 'S'; // OK
ptr = buffer2; // illegal
```

> What I wanted to know is why the convention is to write `const char*` even for variables where you know you are never going to change the pointer. Is it just a matter of taste and style?

Basically, yes.  There is nothing stopping you from writing `const char * const` if you KNOW you are not going to change the pointer.  It is just not a *requirement*, so it is very easy to omit the `const` on the pointer itself.  What is more important is the type of data that the pointer is pointing at.

Comment: This answer describes the meaning of the syntax, but the question wasn't about what the syntax means.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica I have updated my answer